# Pandas, groupby include number of rows grouped in each row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Have any way to use

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'a.xlsx')
df2 = df.groupby(by=["col"], as_index=False).mean()
```

Include new column with number of rows grouped in each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- in absence of sample data,  I'm assuming you have multiple numeric columns
- can use `apply()` to then calculate all **means** and append `len()` to this series

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col": np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 200),
        "val": np.random.uniform(1, 5, 200),
        "val2": np.random.uniform(5, 10, 200),
    }
)
df2 = df.groupby(by=["col"], as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.select_dtypes("number").mean().append(pd.Series({"len": len(d)}))
)
df2
```

|  | col | val | val2 | len |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 3.13064 | 7.63837 | 42 |
| 1 | B | 3.1057 | 7.50656 | 44 |
| 2 | C | 3.0111 | 7.82628 | 54 |
| 3 | D | 3.20709 | 7.32217 | 60 |

#### comment code

```
def w_avg(df, values, weights, exp):
    d = df[values]
    w = df[weights] ** exp
    return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()


dfg1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Jogador": np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 200),
        "Evento": np.random.choice(list("XYZ"),200),
        "Rating Calculado BW": np.random.uniform(1, 5, 200),
        "Lances": np.random.uniform(5, 10, 200),
    }
)

dfg = dfg1.groupby(by=["Jogador", "Evento"]).apply(
    lambda dfg1: dfg1.select_dtypes("number")
    .agg(lambda d: w_avg(dfg1, "Rating Calculado BW", "Lances", 1))
    .append(pd.Series({"len": len(dfg1)}))
)

dfg
```

Comment: Excellent! Very efficient and economic solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: happy it helps - for SO consider accepting answers that solve your question

Comment: Thank you again! I tried use avg weighted instead mean, but maybe I do anything wrong... 
 
'''
def w_avg(df, values, weights, exp):
    d = df[values]
    w = df[weights]**exp
    return (d*w).sum() / w.sum()

dfg = dfg1.groupby(by=["Jogador", "Evento"]).apply(lambda dfg1: dfg1.select_dtypes("number").apply(w_avg, 'Rating Calculado BW', 'Lances', 1).append(pd.Series({"len": len(dfg1)})))
'''

Comment: no idea what your data looks like or what you are trying.  you are intermixing data frames, series and naming conventions are weird for understandable encapsulation.  try updated answer.  or ask a new question which is reproducible